# Invoke-RestMethod - restAPI call fails with an error of 'Invalid flavor'

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how to post a sample post on the RegEx101, using their restAPI, specifically [Create an Entry](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/wiki/API#create-an-entry-) example. There are not any code examples provided for PowerShell, I tried to figure it out using the documentation for `Invoke-RestMethod`, here is what I have:

```
$body   = @{
    regex       = "hello"
    flags       = "i"
    delimiter   = """"
    flavour     = "net"   # I also tried "python" and "pcre"
    testString  = "hello world"
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://regex101.com/api/regex"  -Body $body
```

but the above fails with an error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: 
Line |
  11 |  Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://regex101.com/api/regex"  …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | {"error":"Invalid flavor","errorId":"82fe9139-a234-492d-b59e-8c6f99b9e3f8"}
```

I tried changing the flavour to `pthon` and even `pcre` but the error persists, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The Correct Content-Type for JSON
JSON has to be correctly interpreted by the browser to be used appropriately. text/plain was typically used for JSON, but according to IANA, the official MIME type for JSON is application/json.

This means when you're sending JSON to the server or receiving JSON from the server, you should always declare the Content-Type of the header as application/json as this is the standard that the client and server understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API appears to use the US English spelling of 'flavor' rather than 'flavour'

In addition 'net' does not appear to be a valid option.  It worked for me when I used 'python'

Comment: You are right. Its a shame about the lack of .NET support for the API. I will open an issue and ask them to consider it. Thank you for the help.